# How to add variables (coming from a cell) in web queries in MS Excel 2010?

Tags: excel, ms-office, redmine, excel-2010

So, I have the excel sheet pulling data from web API call, which responds in xml format. I can successfully pull it, populate it, and work with it. And since it's a get call with some parameters appended to the query, I want those parameters to come from a cell in a separate sheet (in the same workbook) so that the user can change the cell instead of the query itself.

Is it possible? How do I do it? Will it make a new API call to get the data when the content of that cell is modified or does the user have to click on Refresh?

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**: I have tried to use something like this: `http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=[“symbol”, “Enter ticker symbol”]` like defined [here](http://www.aaii.com/computerized-investing/article/using-excel-web-queries-to-retrieve-data), but when I click Import, it gives me 404 and I just can't figure out how to do it.

The API call I'm making is to our Redmine machine and I'm using [this Redmine API call](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Rest_Issues)

Comment: Just to clarify, the "separate sheet" is still in the same workbook?

Comment: How is the API called? Is it a query using VBA (i.e. MSXML/XMLHTTP), is it using the built-in query tool, something else?

Comment: @hardmath: yes it is still same workbook.

Comment: @JP. I'm using Data -> From Web -> Entering a query in "Address" -> Import. It's an external call to our Redmine machine using this API call: http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Rest_Issues

Comment: My guess is you would need to use VBA to take the cell value(s) and run the query for you.